# inserção de Array organizado em Array para uso posterior como variável

Tags: javascript, array

Em um arquivo JavaScript, possuo o seguinte grupo de arrays:

```
logo: [
  require('@/assets/images/logos/lojas-' + cobrand[0] + '.png'),
  require('@/assets/images/logos/lojas-' + cobrand[1] + '.png'),
  require('@/assets/images/logos/lojas-' + cobrand[2] + '.png'),
  require('@/assets/images/logos/lojas-' + cobrand[3] + '.png')
]
```

Cada `require` faz referência a uma imagem existente na pasta `logos`, onde cada imagem tem o nome da loja, como a seguir:

```
let cobrand = [
  'informatica',
  'mercearia',
  'locadora',
  'padaria'
]
```

Então, dentro da pasta `logo` tenho uma imagem para cada `cobrand`:

```
lojas-informatica.png
lojas-mercearia.png
lojas-locadora.png
lojas-padaria.png
```

Como só tem 4 itens, ficou bem simples utilizar a forma que está nesta pergunta, criar um array com tudo igual mudando apenas o `index` do `cobrand[i]`.

Só que, quando isso ficar maior, se tornará bastante custoso. Existe uma forma de fazer o array `logo` ter 1 linha apenas com todos os `cobrands`?

Pensei em utilizar o `concat` como neste exemplo que aprendi em outra pergunta:

```
[].concat(arrayum, arraydois, [ 'valueum', 'valuedois' ])
```

Porém isso de forma simples, fará com que todos os `cobrand` entrem juntos na URL, o que não é o caso que procuro.

não posso criar uma function a não ser que seja dentro da linha do array `logo: [].function aqui` ou o `for` desde que seja dentro deste array também

Comment: Mas não é só fazer um `for` em **cobrand[]** e nos **required** colocar  cobrand[i] ??

Comment: @LeAndrade não posso fazer uma function

Comment: Hmmm, aí complica em man, ter um arquivo Javascript e não poder criar uma função, é mesma coisa que ir em Maresias e não gostar de areia.

Comment: Se entendi direito o que você quer fazer é algo do tipo `logo: cobrand.map(nome => require(\`@/assets/images/logos/lojas-${nome}.png\`))`. É isso?

Comment: vou testar aqui, aparentemente é isso mesmo, ele irá criar um array com todas as opções dentro do cobrand, vou testar e te falo

Comment: @user140828 exato, no console ele criou um array com todas as imagens sem executar erro, muito bom, isso está muito certo

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se se entendi bem o problema ...mas se a intenção for estocar os paths das suas logos de uma maneira fácil de usar (e reusar), ao invés de usar um **array [ ... ]**, vc poderia guardá-los dentro de um **Objeto { ... }** já com os caminhos das prontos inclusive. Assim:

```
let cobrandUrls = {
  informatica: '@/assets/images/logos/lojas-informatica.png',
  mercearia: '@/assets/images/logos/lojas-mercearia.png',
  locadora: '@/assets/images/logos/lojas-locadora.png',
  padaria: '@/assets/images/logos/lojas-padaria.png'
}
```

Daí, quando vc precisar usar uma logo, bastará acessar a propriedade desejada dentro do objeto.

Lembrando que vc pode acessar o valor da propriedade de um Objeto tanto usando a sintaxe de ponto **objeto.prorpiedade** quanto a sintaxe de colchetes **objeto['propriedade']**, dá no mesmo!

```
cobrandUrls.informatica    //  @/assets/images/logos/lojas-informatica.png
cobrandUrls['mercearia']    //  @/assets/images/logos/lojas-mercearia.png
```

Assim, de posse da variável **cobrandUrls**, como definida acima, já vc pode sair usando seus paths aonde quiser!

Por exemplo...
com HTML e JS puro:

```
// html
<img id="logo-img" />

// js
const img = document.getElementById('logo-img')
img.setAttribute('src', cobrandUrls.padaria)
```

exemplo com React

```
<img src={cobrandUrls.padaria} />
```

exemplo com Angular

```
<img [src]="cobrandUrls.padaria" />
```

Se por algum motivo vc precisar percorrer todas as logos de cobrandUrls pode facilmente iterar as chaves do Objeto usando **Object.keys()**, os valores contidos em cada chave com **Object.values()** ou então iterar **Object.entries()** que retorna tanto chave quanto valor:

```
for (const chave of Object.keys(cobrand)){
  console.log(chave)
}
// informatica
// mercearia
// locadora
// padaria

for (const valor of Object.values(cobrand)){
  console.log(valor)
}
//  '@/assets/images/logos/lojas-informatica.png',
//  '@/assets/images/logos/lojas-mercearia.png',
//  etc..


for (let [chave, valor] of Object.entries(cobrand)){
  console.log(chave + ' : ' + valor)
}

// informatica : @/assets/images/logos/lojas-informatica.png
// mercearia : @/assets/images/logos/lojas-mercearia.png
// etc..
```

Aqui nos exemplos estou apenas dando um console.log em cada item, porém acho que já dá pra imaginar o quanto isso pode ser útil pois te permite criar lógicas sob medida, pra trabalhar cada valor dentro do objeto como bem entender.

Na verdade tudo isso também seria possível com um array de urls...porém, como vc mesmo já disse, arrays não tem chaves, apenas indices numéricos, daí se o array crescer, vc terá que saber a posição exata de cada item que deseja ou então criar uma função pra descobrir...o que pode até funcionar, mas com certeza tornará seu trabalho mais pesado e seu código menos legível.